# $\Gamma(1/2)$ and the Euler reflection formula

Tags: complex-analysis

With Euler's reflection formula we can show that $\Gamma(1/2)^2=\pi$.

Why can't $\Gamma(1/2)=-\sqrt \pi$  ?

Comment: The defining integral has a positive integrand and is evaluated over $ \ (0, \ +\infty) \ $ -- could that be negative?

Comment: Because $\Gamma(1/2)$ is the integral over $(0,\infty)$ of a positive function, so it must be positive

Comment: because $\ln \Gamma(x)$ is convex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\Gamma\left(\frac 1 2 \right) = \int_0^\infty x^{(1/2)-1} e^{-x}\, dx > 0.
$$
If you integrate a function whose values are positive over a positively oriented interval, then the value of the integral is positive.

("Integrating over a positively oriented interval" means $\displaystyle\int_a^b$ where $a<b$, as opposed to $\displaystyle\int_a^b \text{ where } a>b$.)